# Navigation Drawer is not clickable

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer in all of my activities **(NOTE: NOT FRAGMENT)**. I did so and I even initialize onNavigationItemSelected but my menu are still not clickable. As in, the navigation drawer does indeed slide right but the menu options are not clickable and does not go to the next activity.

I have two types of menu - one is the navigation drawer on the top right and another is the ellipsis type on the top left. My top left is working fine but not the navigation drawer.

Below are my codes for navigation drawer:

---

**at OnCreate:**

```
nv = findViewById(R.id.nvNavView);
nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.navKnowledge:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, KnowledgeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
        case R.id.navRules:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, RulesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

**onCreateOptions:**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   //        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, 
    menu);
        return true;
    }
```

---

**drawer layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#f9f0e1"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvNavView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoKnowledge"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebgpurple">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebgpurple">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_knowledge"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Knowledge"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#3a00a4"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Search Knowledge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoRules"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebgpink"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_rules"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Business Rules"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#ed9bd5"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Search Biz. Rules"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoFaq"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebgyellow"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_faq"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="FAQ"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#fbff00"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Clear Doubts Here"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoQuery"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebggreen"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_query"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Query"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#00a700"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Submit New Query"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoProfile"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebglightpink"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#004ba7"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="My Personal Details"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondtoHelp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circlebgorange"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlewhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_help"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Help"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="#f29d60"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Help &amp; Information"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**navigation menu xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navKnowledge"
    android:title="Search Knowledge"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_knowledge"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navRules"
    android:title="Search Biz. Rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rules"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navFaq"
    android:title="FAQ"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_faq"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navQuery"
    android:title="Submit New Query"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_query"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navProfile"
    android:title="My Account"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

<item android:id="@+id/navHelp"
    android:title="Help &amp; Navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"/>
```

---

I commented out the menu inflater for navigation drawer because although they are clickable, the menu appeared as the 3 dots on top left instead of where i wanted it to be (top right corner and the menu is the 3 lines type).

Does anyone know if I'm doing it wrong somewhere? Can guide me through?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the layout that contains the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: @MikeM See my updated post, thanks

Comment: The `<NavigationView>` needs to be listed last within the `<DrawerLayout>`. Move it to after the outermost `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: @MikeM Wow I totally did not know that the arrangement of the layout played a part!! >.<" I thought the mistake lies on my java codes. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Yeah, `View`s are added on the z-axis in the order they're listed, starting with the `View` furthest away, or "on the bottom". Your drawer was ending up underneath the main content, which was consuming the touch events. Anyhoo, glad it worked for you. Cheers!